# Pseudo-class of :nextTo?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Let's say I have the following HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li id="1">First issue.</li>
    <li id="2" class="error">Second issue.</li>
    <li id="3" class="error">Third issue.</li>
    <li id="4">Fourth issue.</li>
    <li id="5" class="error">Fifth issue.</li>
    <li id="6" class="error">Sixth issue.</li>
    <li id="7" class="error">Seventh issue.</li>
    <li id="8" class="error">Eighth issue.</li>
    <li id="9">Ninth issue.</li>
    <li id="10" class="error">Tenth issue.</li>
</ul>
```

And the following CSS:

```
.error {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

What I'm looking to do is to style the first and last `<li>` in a sequence styled different than other `<li>`s that are in the middle.

For example, `#2, #5, #10` should all match the "first in sequence selector"; `#3, #8, #10` should be matched by the "last in sequence selector."

I'd like to apply the following styles to "first-in-sequence" and "last-in-sequence", respectively:

```
.firstInSequence {
    border-radius-top-right: 10px;
    border-radius-top-left: 10px;
}

.lastInSequence {
    border-radius-bottom-right: 10px;
    border-radius-bottom-left: 10px;
}
```

Are there selectors I could use to do this natively in CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the other answers, you can style the 'first of sequence' using the `:not` and `:first-child` pseudo selector:

```
:not(.error) + .error,
.error:first-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}
```

I think I've found a solution for 'last of sequence' in this scenario with rounded corners. It uses a completely different *method* of accomplishing the finished product, but ends with a similar result:

[image: Rounded Corners on last of sequence]

The basic technique is to apply pseudo-elements with `radial-gradients` to list items that are not  `.error.` after `.error`s, and move them up over the previous (`.error`) list item:

```
.error + :not(.error):before {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
    left:0;
    background:-webkit-radial-gradient(100% 0,circle,transparent 10px,white 0);
}

.error + :not(.error):after {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
    right:0;
    background:-webkit-radial-gradient(0 0,circle,transparent 10px,white 0);
}
```

Make sure `li` has `position:relative;`.

Finally, for a `border-radius` on the last one, use `last-of-type`:

```
.error:last-of-type{
    border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:10px
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VQY2Z/1/) (Webkit only for simplicity)

Comment: Unfortunately, the demo doesn't address #10, it's only rounded on top and not on bottom.

Comment: That can be solved with `:last-of-type`. I updated my answer.

Comment: +1 This is some pretty radical thinking. Only issues I can think of (besides getting it to work cross browser) are: needs a solid color background; requires the margin between list items. The margin thing seems like a deal breaker.

Comment: You may as well use `:last-child` here instead of `:last-of-type`, as the only possible type of child element a `ul` could have is `li`. The class is not relevant.

Comment: If the last child is not guaranteed to have the `error` class, then there's no CSS3 selector for the last child with that class.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be able to cobble together pieces of this to work, but not all of it. But here are my thoughts to start.

Making liberal use of CSS3 [not selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-not) and [adjacent sibling combinator](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/adjacentsiblingselector).

These are the pieces I think you have a chance of doing.

http://jsfiddle.net/PDQMg/

Error is first in list

```
li.error:first-child {  }
<li error />
<li noerror />
...
<li />
```

Error is after a no error.

```
li:not(li.error) + li.error { }
<li noerror />
<li error />
...
<li />
```

Error is last in list

```
li.error:last-child { }
<li />
...
<li class="error" />
```

Comment: +1 Funny we had the same basic idea at the same time. I don't think you need the `:last-child` selector unless you are trying to partially cover the "last in sequence" bit, otherwise `not(.error) + .error` should cover that.

Comment: Yeah I saw your answer and actually liked the syntax better. Unfortunately I don't see any way he can get the last in list property because there is no :before selector in CSS (nor do I think there will be)

Comment: Yeah I think OP is out of gas on that one. Something imaginary like `:not(.error):prev(.error:first)` might work (but sure is ugly). This situation is pretty uncommon though.

Answer (score 2):

For "first in sequence" you can try this, as long as the elements are adjacent:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WkxyP/

```
:not(.error) + .error,
.error:first-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}
```

- `:not(.error) + .error` - The next adjacent element with the class "error" to element without the class "error"
- `.error:first-child` - Any element with class "error" that is the first child of another element, for cases the above selector can't match

I *think* that covers everything. Not sure how to do "last in sequence" with this particular puzzle.

**By the way**: check your property names, should be `border-top-left-radius` instead of `border-radius-top-left`, and so on.

Comment: +1. I 'used' your answer in mine, (although I stumbled across it independently, a [convergent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_evolution) solution, if you will.) However, I didn't simply edit your post because I came up with something pretty out there for the 'last in sequence'. I'm curious to know what you think.